# How does one make a bezier curve in Krita have pressure width like a brush for the stroke?

Tags: krita

Krita question. When drawing with a pen, one can set the pressure of a brush to look like in the image below:

[image: Brush pressure settings]

But Bezier curves end up looking with the same width across the whole curve like in the image below:

[image: Brush stroke vs Bezier curve stroke]

How can one make the Bezier curve have pressure like width across the curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Krita doesn't currently have variable width vector strokes.  There are some work arounds though.

Draw a shape, and apply a fill, but no stroke.

[image]

OR

Use Inkscape, draw a simple path, add a stroke, then use the Power Stroke live path effect to create a variable width stroke, then you can copy and paste it into a vector layer in Krita.

[image]